# I am trying to create a SQL query with multiple AND OR and NOT LIKE commands

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to do this query (updated after comments)

```
SELECT item,short,itemgr FROM DATABASE.ITEM
WHERE marker = 0 and
      itemgr in ('200','201','202','204','205','230','234','236','240','270','285') and
      short NOT LIKE '%AQUA%';
```

The results vary. If I use NOT LIKE after the first bracket with 1 parameter it works (as you can see it in the sample now), but as soon as I try to add a second NOT LIKE command I just get the results from the first bracket.

### EDIT

Original SQL:

```
SELECT item,short,itemgr FROM DATABASE.ITEM
WHERE
 marker = 0 AND (itemgr = '100' OR itemgr = '301' OR itemgr = '405')
AND
(short NOT LIKE '%A%' OR short NOT LIKE '%B%' OR short NOT LIKE '%A%');
```

Comment: Tip: `itemgr IN (100, 301, 405)`

Comment: Hint: regular expression instead of the 3 NOT LIKE.

Comment: Hello, it would help if explain to us (in words) exactly what data you'd like to query.

Comment: What does "it stops working" mean?

Comment: Sample data and expected results (in addition to the explanation of what you want in words) is usually very helpful when you have this sort of request.

Comment: Show the query that doesn't work, along with sample data and results to illustrate the problem.  I note that your query doesn't have any *parameters*, but you do allude to them, which is rather confusing.

Comment: I put the original code from your back into the question so the question can be more easily understood. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear for me what you are trying to achieve but I have 2 advices:

1. Instead of `itemgr = '100' OR itemgr = '301' OR itemgr = '405'"` use `"itemgr in ('100','301','405')"`
2. `"OR short NOT LIKE '%A%'"` is redundant

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to filter out several things, like the short column contains mixed data and I try to filter out the one I don't like to see.
Example be like data is 123 A, 125 B, 205 F, and I only like to see the values without letters. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get items that don't match a series of like conditions, I would suggest regular expressions.  Perhaps what you want is:

```
SELECT item, short, itemgr
FROM DATABASE.ITEM i
WHERE i.marker = 0 and
      i.itemgr in ('200', '201', '202', '204', '205', '230', '234', '236', '240', '270', '285') and
      not regexp_like(short, 'AQUA|TERRA')
```

Answer (score 0):

Negative logic is always difficult to understand. Try to write code in which you state what you want instead of what you **don't** want.

In this case, instead of looking for values in `SHORT` which **don't** contain letters, look for values which **do** contain the characters you care about:

```
SELECT item,short,itemgr
  FROM DATABASE.ITEM
  WHERE marker = 0 AND
        (itemgr = '100' OR itemgr = '301' OR itemgr = '405') AND
        REGEXP_LIKE(SHORT, '^[0-9 ]+$')
```

In this case this regular expression says that the query will only accept rows where the value of SHORT consists entirely of the characters `'0'`, `'1'`, ..., `'9'`, and `' '`.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4e985ab9730dedcf659963390ebb5b2c)

Regular expressions are a useful tool. If you're not familiar with them I suggest finding a resource (book, web site, etc) to help you learn about them.